Apache eCharts Angular draw markLine over stack
I have a line chart with a markLine that shows the current date. Unfortunately, the line is displayed below the other stack series. Setting the zLevel did not help either.
{
  // .. other config 
  series: [
    { name: '1', type: 'line', stack: 'Total', areaStyle: { opacity: 1 }, showSymbol: false, data: [...], z: 10 },
    { name: '2', type: 'line', stack: 'Total', areaStyle: { opacity: 1 }, showSymbol: false, data: [...], z: 20 },
    // MarkLine 
    { name: '2', type: 'line', zLevel: 100, markLine: { label: { show: false, showLabel: false }, symbol: 'none', data: [ { symbol: 'none', xAxis: 'xxx', zLevel: 100 } ] } },
  ]
}

The line is displayed correctly, but unfortunately below the other lines. Do you have any idea how I can get it above the other lines?

Actually, the z property should be bit less and also, the markline, can just be defined on one of the traces.
option = {
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked Line'
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis'
  },
  legend: {
    data: ['Email', 'Union Ads', 'Video Ads', 'Direct', 'Search Engine']
  },
  grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '4%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true
  },
  toolbox: {
    feature: {
      saveAsImage: {}
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: '1',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      areaStyle: { opacity: 1 },
      showSymbol: false,
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      z: 1
    },
    {
      name: '2',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      areaStyle: { opacity: 1 },
      showSymbol: false,
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      z: 1,
      markLine: {
        data: [
          {
            label: { show: false, showLabel: false },
            yAxis: 6,
            lineStyle: {
              color: '#000'
            },
            symbol: 'none',
            data: [{ symbol: 'none', xAxis: 'xxx', zLevel: 100 }]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    // MarkLine
  ]
};

CodePen Demo

i tried zLevel but the Z did the job. thanks.
